# CLLocationManager is not working in the iOS 4.3 simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, cllocationmanager

I'm using CLLocationManager to determine my current location:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;
    NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (locationAge > 5.0) return;
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;
    if (self.currentLocation == nil || self.currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy > newLocation.horizontalAccuracy) {
        self.currentLocation = newLocation;
    }
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

It works in iOS 5.1 simulator but not in iOS 4.3 simulator, and I think it might be a problem in real devices before iOS 5.1. Why is it not working?

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by 'not working'. Are the delegate methods not getting called at all? Maybe try setting desiredAccuracy filter. Check the authorization status. Implement the didFail method and see if it's dropping down into there

Comment: Make sure that you check `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` before trying to use `CCLocationManager` your location services could be turned off, even in the simulator.

Comment: I've tried "locationServicesEnabled" method and you are right Joe, Location services is not enabled. So how can I enable it or what should I do?

Comment: You will need to go into settings in the simulator. From there you should be able to turn location services on.

Comment: I understand why. ios simulator 4.3 does not support the location service but I think my code will work in real device.

Comment: I am also having the same problem. did you get any solution for that ?

Comment: Try running that same code in a ios 6 or ios 5 simulater and tell me in the comments if it worked...

Comment: yes it is working in ios 5 and ios 6 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS simulator does not support simulated locations before iOS 5. The problem you are having is a limitation of the simulator.